# How do i set framebuffer console font > 32x16?

Tags: console, fonts, framebuffer

I need a to set a font larger than **32x16** for my framebuffer console. As far as i know 32 is the maximum you can do.

Is there a workaround? I'm fine with starting an alternate framebuffer terminal (but which one?). I can't run X and i can't lower the resolution of my display.

My `/etc/default/console-setup` looks like this:

```
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="32x16"
```

Something like 40xSomething would be the sweet spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit late, but `fbterm` can do it `fbterm -s 40`

Comment: `sudo apt install fbterm` on Debian (RaspberryPi)

Comment: Lifesaver. If your console font is too small so as to be unreadable in the frame buffer, this is what you’re looking for.

Comment: This command kind of works on Debian 12, however, on laptops with two built-in screens like Zenbook duo it creates garbled experience. Perhaps fb is not able to calculate rows properly.